# Mac randomly wakes up. Wake reason: (User)

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

My mac randomly wakes up for no reason and says the user is the reason, when it is not. Here's `syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"`:

```
Feb 25 20:13:44 Garys-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 17:41:46 Garys-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 17:51:59 Garys-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 19:26:43 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 19:28:56 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 22:15:40 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 23:28:37 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 23:35:09 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  1 23:43:30 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  2 01:43:36 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  2 11:26:12 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  2 13:57:37 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
Mar  2 16:54:12 Garys-MBP kernel[0] <Notice>: Wake reason: (User)
```

Here's `pmset -g` and `assertions`:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power          -1
AC Power          -1*
Currently in use:
womp                 1
halfdim              1
sms                  1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
gpuswitch            2
networkoversleep     1
disksleep            10
sleep                0
hibernatemode        1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         5 (display sleep prevented by remoting_me2me_)
acwake               0
lidwake              1
Garys-MBP:~ Gary$ pmset -g assertions
2015-03-02 17:47:50 +0000
Assertion status system-wide:
BackgroundTask                 0
ApplePushServiceTask           0
UserIsActive                   1
PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    1
PreventSystemSleep             0
ExternalMedia                  0
InternalPreventDisplaySleep    1
PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 315(remoting_me2me_): [0x0000954900050599] 00:04:44   NoDisplaySleepAssertion named: "Chrome Remote Desktop connection active"
   pid 315(remoting_me2me_): [0x000095490009059a] 00:04:44 UserIsActive named: "Chrome Remote Desktop connection active"
   pid 27(powerd): [0x0000954300100428] 00:04:50 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff"
     Timeout will fire in 298 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
Kernel Assertions: 0x100=MAGICWAKE
   id=502  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=02/03/2015 16:58 description=en0 owner=en0
```

Edit: I still have the same problem but a different assertions results:

```
2015-03-03 19:31:47 +0000 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 1
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   0
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
    pid 225(UserEventAgent): [0x00013ade000b0ac9] 08:35:55 BackgroundTask    named: "com.apple.bird.sync"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the Chrome Remote Desktop app installed and active.

That one is waking up your computer as show here:

```
pid 315(remoting_me2me_): [0x0000954900050599] 00:04:44   NoDisplaySleepAssertion named: "Chrome Remote Desktop connection active"

pid 315(remoting_me2me_): [0x000095490009059a] 00:04:44 UserIsActive named: "Chrome Remote Desktop connection active"

pid 27(powerd): [0x0000954300100428] 00:04:50 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff"
```

What to do about it [read here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en).

Also you have the MAGICWAKE activated. Disable the Wake on WiFi in your syst pref- Energy to stop that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not solved my problem. Edited the main thread with more.